# What is the difference between inclusive measurements and differential measurements?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, measurements

While reading about the current status of the top quark analysis at LHC I come across these two terms: inclusive measurement and differential measurement? What do they mean?

[I came across another stack exchange question which explains the inclusive part but doesn't mention about differential measurement?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1217/)

Is differential measurement just a subset of exclusive measurements?

Comment: Differential measurement gives the production  crossections as a function of some variable,(example  a plot versus angle to be compared with theory) inclusive integrate over the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, differential measurement is a subset of exclusive measurements with the particle angular distribution information.

Comment: This is a rather short answer and may be more suitable as a comment. Can you add a bit more detail to it?